# How to gather an array of objects that contains an array of objects inside a property

Tags: ios, iphone, filewrapper

I am trying to create a file wrapper of the kind package to put stuff inside.

I have this code:

```
class Documents {
  static func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
  }
}
```

later in code

```
let documentsURL = Documents.getDocumentsDirectory()
    
let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("myFile.tb")
do {
   let mainFileWrapper = try FileWrapper(url: fileURL, options: [])
```

error on the last line:

```
{Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("myFile.tb")` you are not creating a file at that place.

You need to make sure that file exists at that place. You can check that if it already exists, if it doesn't you can create it.

```
let documentsURL = Documents.getDocumentsDirectory()
let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("myFile.tb")
do {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: fileURL.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
    }
    let mainFileWrapper = try FileWrapper(url: fileURL, options: [])
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

From [FileWrapper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filewrapper) docs -

> A representation of a node (a file, directory, or symbolic link) in the file system.

So a file (even empty/new file), folder or a symlink is necessary to be present at the url/path using which you are creating a `FileWrapper` instance.

Comment: I don't get it. The file wrapper is the way to create special kind of files. How can I create it previously?

Comment: and how will I create a file wrapper on disk?